# All my reputation disappeared from stackoverflow.com

Tags: support

I came to stackoverflow.com today, and saw I wasn't logged in, so I logged in again using gmail, then I saw all my reputation and asked questions and entire history disappeared! Can you restore it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of one of the questions you've previously asked?

Comment: [Dup?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist)

Comment: That's odd, Game Dev and Tex also show 1 rep. Did you per chance associate these accounts after logging in today, or did you find them associated automatically once logged in?

Comment: You seem to have two accounts [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/users/781214) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1213822), with the newest one associated with other sites. Strange, I don't see activity on _either_ of them.

Comment: I had more than 100 points and several badges, till yesterday. However, I think I know what happened. I commented [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480037/chat-in-an-iphone-app) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707546/chat-in-iphone-sdk) two similar answers (which directed to an SDK I wrote) and I guess it deleted my account assuming I'm spam or something... Can you revive me?

Comment: Is there an automatic account deleter system for that?That is what I understand from Kalisky's last comment @TimPost .I got banned for some weeks several times and my reputation and stuff was gone too, but it wasn't automatic I received an email from the legend(Mr.Atwood) saying I was banned temporarily.

Comment: @RoboLover I know cookie accounts expire after a while, and I _think_ accounts that have been completely inactive since being created also have a shelf life. But I don't think accounts that have earned some reputation are affected by that. The tools I have just don't give me enough information to explain why there's no trace of him earning over 100 rep (on either one).

Comment: @TimPost That is a very interesting situation and it seems very unlikely to restore Kalisky's reputation for now.

Comment: I've pinged a community coordinator to take a deeper look. As @balpha said, if you can remember an up voted post you wrote, a link to it might unravel this mystery.

Comment: Looks like Bill killed the account.

Comment: @CodeInChaos What makes you say it was Bill?

Comment: @jadarnel27 He deleted both answers, so it's likely he also killed the account for spamming.

Comment: It does indeed look like your account was destroyed for spamming. I was thrown off because I found two healthy accounts with no activity that belong to you (one eight months old) and didn't notice your follow up comment. I suggest you just use [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/users/781214) and avoid posts that look like advertisements :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your answers appeared to be promoting an SDK and nothing else then they could well be regarded as spam. Identical answers to different questions would reinforce that view.

It looks like the account was destroyed by a moderator. You could e-mail the team @ stackoverflow.com to see if they can restore the account.

To avoid this happening again be *very* careful about [self promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion)

Comment: Isn't the team supposed to send an email or something?

Comment: @RoboLover - that's for suspension. If the moderator thought it was a clear cut case of spamming then I can see why they wouldn't. Particularly if it was an unregistered account (less likely on SO though).

Comment: Allright then, but I still think it is good to send an email in such situations.

Comment: I agree, it's a good SDK that answers what the guy wanted and I suggested it, so maybe it counts for spam, but why not sending me an email saying that? too harsh IMHO. Sending team an email. Thanks

Comment: @Kalisky, Your "spam" answers weren't particularly useful. They'd be akin to me posting an answer to someone asking about C# saying "look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/ for C# stuff". Relevant, yes. Helpful, err, no. By all means provide a link to the SDK, but give some context and explain why it would be useful with regard to the SPECIFIC question, even better, provide a code snippet that shows how to use it in the context of the question. Just dumping a link and some praise for the SDK will result in the posts being treated  (and rightly so) as spam

Comment: Ok, I guess I got it, especially with such a strong "delete" accord... won't happen again, and sorry. Now can please someone get me back my user?!